# ¿Como puedo sumar los elementos de las columnas impares de una matriz de enteros y guardarlos en una variable?

Tags: java

Amigos, no sé cómo empezar a desarrollar este método, alguna idea!! Necesito sumar los elementos de las columnas impares de una matriz de enteros y guardarlos en una variable. Gracias por la atención.Este metodo me suma todas las columnas yo quiero clasificar las pares y las impares para almasenar la suma en dos variables distintas.

```
public static int calculos(int[][] matriz) {
    int resultado = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            resultado = resultado + matriz[i][j];

        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu duda exactamente? ¿Que has intentado? Las preguntas sin codigo son consideradas de mala calidad y acaban cerradas.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Empieza por algo mas simple, como recorrer y sumar toda la matriz...

Comment: colega mi problema esta en identificar las columnnas impares de la matriz q me dan, puesto a q no la conozco

Comment: Sabes como recorrer una matriz?

Comment: con dos for anidados, uno para las filas y otro para las columnas

Comment: public static int calculos(int[][] matriz) {
        int resultado = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
                resultado = resultado + matriz[i][j];

            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }

Comment: ese que esta ahi me suma todas las columnas yo solo quiero que me sue las pares y las almasene en una variable y las impares las almasene en otra

Comment: poen ese codigo como una edicion a tu pregunta. Usa el boton [edit]

Comment: ahora.. otra consulta... sabes como funciona el for? sabes que no necesariamente tiene que empezar en 0? sabes que no necesariamente tiene que ir de 1 en 1??? pensalo ;)

Comment: ese codigo lo acabo de hacer yo, no e trabajado mucho con matrices pero si con array y con for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La instruccion For en cualquier lenguaje, permite definir el punto de partida, y tambien permite definir el incremento de la variable que se usa para iterar en cualquier monto.

Por lo tanto, si uno quisiera recorrer una array desde la mitad, podria hacer algo asi:

```
for (int j = matriz[0].length/2...
```

Y ese j, empezaria por la mitad..

Tambien podriamos empezar por el ultimo elemento

```
for (int j = matriz[0].length...
```

O, para este caso.. empezar por el primero que fuera impar

```
for (int j = 1...
```

Entonces, sabiendo que empezamos en uno impar, y que cada numero impar es el anterior mas dos, podriamos iterar de dos en dos.

No solo de dos en dos.. podriamos iterar de 5 en 5.. de 10 en 10.. y como hacemos eso?

de la siguiente forma...

```
for (...; j=j+2)
```

Va a ir de 2 en 2

```
for (...; j=j+5)
```

va a ir sumando 5 a j

```
for (...; j=j+10)
```

va a ir sumando 10 a j..

con lo cual, para recorrer los impares, podriamos hacer:

```
for (int j = 1; j < matriz[0].length; j=j+2)
```

Es mas!!!! tambien podriamos ir para atras...

```
for (int j = matriz[0].length; j > 0; j=j-2)
```

Aunque, en este caso, habria que comprobar si la matriz tiene columnas pares o impares (esto ultimo ejemplo, aunque no te sirve, te lo pongo para que pienses)

Te recomendaria leer la teoria de como funciona un for, en cualquier lenguaje.

Comment: gracias amigo duda aclarada al 100% ya termine el codigo

Comment: @DamianAndreu de nada.. pero veo que no realizaste el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio. Te recomiendo que lo hagas, y que despues revises todas las preguntas que hiciste y aceptes las respuestas que son correctas y solucionaron tu pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

pon a sumar el for de tal forma que te coja la posicion impar

Comment: eso es lo q no se

Comment: Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]