# ¿Como cambio el orden de esta Matriz?

Tags: java

Miren , este el el código de la matriz

```
package Prac23_MatrizDinamica;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prac23_MatrizDinamica {

  public static void main(String args[]){

   int filas = 0, columnas = 0, contador = 1;

   Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    //pide el número de filas que debe tener la matriz
System.out.print("¿Cuantas filas necesita la Matriz Dinamica?: ");
   filas = teclado.nextInt();


   //pide el número de columnas que debe tener la matriz
   System.out.print("¿Cuantas columnas necesita la Matriz Dinamica?: ");
   columnas = teclado.nextInt();


   /*Aquí declare la matriz con el número de filas y columnas
    que el programa nos pidío*/
   int MatrizDinamica[][] = new int [filas][columnas];


    //Salto de línea
    System.out.println("");


    /*a continuación iniciamos los ciclos donde la "variable f" representa las 
      filas y la "variable i" las columnas donde cada que termina el ciclo 
      con la "variable i"(el de las columnas) seguidamente
      se agrega otra fila(que es representada por la "variable i" ) */

   /*Aquí el ciclo se detendrá hasta que el número de filas sea menor
   al número que ingresamos(contando que en un Array el primer índice 
   es cero) */
   for( int j = 0; j < filas; j++ ){ 

   /*Aquí este subciclo se detendrá hasta que el número de columnas
    sea menor al número que ingresamos cuando lo pedía el programa*/
   for( int i = 0; i < columnas; i++){

    //Aguardamos la variable "contador" en los índices de la matriz "j" e "i"  
      MatrizDinamica[j][i] = contador;

    //Imprimimos el valor que se encuentra en los indices "j" e "i" en la matriz
     System.out.print("[" + MatrizDinamica[j][i] + "]");
        contador++;
      }
      System.out.println("");/*Da aun salto de línea para que se imprima
      la siguiente fila*/
    }
  }
}
```

Ahora si nosotros al ejecutar el programa , en la parte que nos pide las filas y las columnas , nosotros le asignamos que sean 3 de cada una ,  osea 3 columnas y 3 filas , se imprimirá lo siguiente :

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]
```

Aquí viene la gran pregunta
¿Que es lo que debo hacer para que la matriz se imprima de la siguiente manera?:

```
[1][4][6]
[2][5][7]
[3][6][8]
```

Tengo que recalcar que no se vale repetir el siguiente código tres veces:

```
     for( int j = 0; j < filas; j++ ){
      for( int i = 0; i < columnas; i++){
        MatrizDinamica[j][i] = contador;
        System.out.print("[" + MatrizDinamica[j][i] + "]");
        contador++;
      }
      System.out.println("");
```

Solamente se debe ocupar una vez , osea solamente ocupar dos ciclos "for", una para la variable "j" y otra para la variable "i"

Comment: Tengo serias dudas, de que estas preguntando lo mismo que se pregunta [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/276693/324)

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
int filas=3;
int columnas=3;
int contador = columnas-(columnas-filas);
String resultado = "";

for( int j = 0; j < filas; j++ ){
  int tmp = 0;
  for( int i = 0; i < columnas; i++){
  // sumamos j+1 para que empieze en 1 y no en 0
  // y luego le sumamos la variable tmp
  resultado += "["+ ((j+1)+tmp) +"]";
  //tmp no sera solo igual a columnas
  // porque para 4 columnas fallaria
  tmp+=contador; 
  }
  resultado += "\n"; // salto de linea para el siguiente nivel
}
System.out.print(resultado);
```

Comment: creo que se puede cambiar contador = 0, ponerlo en lugar de tmp, y al final de cada iteracion interna contador += filas;.. de esa forma si la matriz no es cuadrada tambien funciona sin problemas...

Comment: no entendi la parte en donde la variable "tmp" no sera solo  igual a columnas, osea como, ¿"tmp" se utilizo para columnas aparte de la variable "i"?

Comment: @OscarIvanLopez en una matris de 3 `tmp` sera igual `0` luego `3` luego `6` para que en la primera iteracion sea `[1]` y luego `[4]` y luego `[7]`

Comment: Oye en esta línea de código: `resultado +=  "\n";` Para que se utilizo `+=` yo que sepa solo es un operador de asignación, pero no hay un valor después de este , solo un salto de línea `"\n";`

Answer (score -1):

int filas = 0, columnas = 0, contador = 1;

```
       Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        //pide el número de filas que debe tener la matriz
    System.out.print("¿Cuantas filas necesita la Matriz Dinamica?: ");
       filas = teclado.nextInt();
       //pide el número de columnas que debe tener la matriz
       System.out.print("¿Cuantas columnas necesita la Matriz Dinamica?: ");
       columnas = teclado.nextInt();
       int i;
       int j;
       int matriza[][]=new int[filas][columnas];

       Scanner dato = new Scanner (System.in);
       System.out.println("Escribir datos de la matriz ");

           for (i=0;i<=2;i++){
               for (j=0;j<=2;j++){
                   System.out.print("Escribir valor " + i + " , " + j + " : ");
                   matriza [i][j] = dato.nextInt();
               }
           }
           System.out.println("MATRIZ 3x3");
           for (i=0;i<=2;i++){
       for (j=0;j<=2;j++){
       System.out.print("["+matriza[i][j]+"]");
       }
       System.out.println("");
       }
```

[image: Salida en consola]

Comment: jajaja, bueno gracias por la respuesta, pero yo quiero que el  programa rellene la matriz solo con asignarle el numero de  las filas y columnas cuando el programa lo pida, no agregar uno por uno